# External script support from xxforms:script?

Tags: orbeon

I needed delayed calling of external scripts until after xforms-ready. Does the xxforms:script element support externals scripts? I could not find documentation like here: http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-actions/actions-script-action E.g.

```
<xxforms:script ev:event="xforms-ready" ref="/script/codemirror/addon/edit/closetag.js"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`xxforms:script` (AKA `xxf:script`) only support inline JavaScript, which is transformed into a JavaScript function with its content as function body. The function is called whenever the given `xxf:script` action is executed.

From `xxforms:script`, however, you can call external JavaScript with the [`oxf.fr.js.custom.uri` property](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/configuration-properties/configuration-properties-form-runner#TOC-Adding-your-own-JavaScript).